# iOS Memory Increasing Issue

Tags: ios, http, core-data, swift, memory-management

I am doing a submittal of built JSON data on a background thread in iOS and while running I see the memory just going up exponentially here which eventually leads to a crash. I have gone through this code a number of times and just can't figure out why the memory is going up as it appears everything would be deallocated during each iteration.

What it does is pull out records from a queue implemented in Core Data and for every 32 of them submits a HTTP PUT request to the server with that data. After each of these iterations it deletes those records and saves the context.

Edit: After testing I have discovered it to be the HTTP part of this. I am still unable to tell what is causing this and forcing more memory. Maybe too many separate connections?

Here is the code:

```
class func startSubmitting()
{
    // If this has already been called then don't go back into it
    if submitThreadRunning
    {
        return
    }

    var mainQueue:NSOperationQueue = NSOperationQueue()

    mainQueue.addOperationWithBlock(
    {
        let url: String = "URL_HERE"

        let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
        let managedContext = NSManagedObjectContext()
        managedContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = appDelegate.persistentStoreCoordinator

        submitThreadRunning = true

        var offSetCount = 0

        var fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName:"Queue")
        var error: NSError?

        var sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "timestamp", ascending: false)
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors?.append(sortDescriptor)

        // Limit to 32 records at a time
        fetchRequest.fetchLimit = 32
        fetchRequest.fetchOffset = offSetCount

        while submitThreadRunning
        {
            if let fetchedResults = managedContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: &error) as? [Queue]
            {
                // If no fetched results, sleep for a bit so as to not hammer the battery life
                if fetchedResults.count == 0
                {
                    NSThread.sleepForTimeInterval(5.0)
                    continue
                }

                var counter = 0
                var data = String(format:"{\"apiKey\": \"%@\", \"data\":[", apiKey!)

                for result in fetchedResults
                {
                    if submitThreadRunning
                    {
                        let count = fetchedResults.count

                        if fetchedResults.count != (counter + 1)
                        {
                            data += result.json + ","

                            // Remove the record
                            managedContext.deleteObject(result)

                            // Update the counter
                            counter++

                            // Update the offset
                            offSetCount++

                            continue
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            data += result.json + "]}"
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // We are stopping so go ahead and finish off the array and continue
                        data += result.json + "]}"
                    }

                    var request: NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest()
                    var response: NSURLResponse?

                    request.URL = NSURL(string: url)
                    request.HTTPMethod = "PUT"
                    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
                    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

                    request.HTTPBody = (data as NSString).dataUsingEncoding(NSASCIIStringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: true)

                    NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse: &response, error: &error)

                    let statusCode = (response as NSHTTPURLResponse).statusCode

                    // Handle any errors
                    if error != nil || statusCode >= 400
                    {
                        // Undo all changes to the data store from this iteration
                        for var i = 0; i < counter - 1; i++
                        {
                            managedContext.undo()
                        }

                        // Update the offest
                        offSetCount++

                        continue
                    }

                    // Remove the record
                    managedContext.deleteObject(result)

                    // Update the offest
                    offSetCount++
                }
            }

            // Save all changes to the data store
            managedContext.save(&error)

            if error != nil
            {
                // TODO Show an error message on the UI Thread
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: "Shortest code to reproduce" is the relevant bit on the close reason. Please pare this down to a smaller program that has the same problem.

Comment: Are you sure `error` is `nil`?

Comment: Use The Tools, Luke.

Comment: After further testing, I have discovered when I take out the HTTP code then the memory doesn't increase. Anybody have a clue about that?

Comment: Oh already did that, it's a TON of mutable strings which is why I am confused. Should have stated that in post above.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution [here](https://gist.github.com/jjthrash/5805749).

It was creating a VERY large cache of all the HTTP requests and responses which is why Instruments was showing 6K+ strings that were created. So once I put in that line of code it worked just fine and no memory issues at all any more. This appears to be something iOS does under the hood and it isn't very well documented in the API docs. So hoping this will help somebody else.